# Installing Ubuntu On An Old PC

Tags: 12.04, installation

I have recently received a new pc and would like to install Ubuntu on my old one.

Can I simply install it and write over the old hard drive, or do I need to do something special?

Comment: You can make a cup of coffe to make the installation more enjoyable.

Comment: can you define old? it might influence which flavor and which version of Ubuntu you should install...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not plan to keep/transfer the information from your old hard drive then you can simply do the installation and overwrite the hard drive, there is **nothing** you have to do beforehand to prepare the hard drive.

If however there is information on the old hard drive that you would like to keep then I would suggest you **backup** the contents of that old hard drive before you do the installation.

Answer (score -1):

***YES, you can just install it.***

Try installing **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS**.

---

*If you have an issue (while installing), this is the forum for help ..*

Comment: Why in the world would you suggest a 64bit version if you don't know of the OP's hardware? Also you should explain LTS to new users.